# Java http connection

Tags: java, http, https

I want setup a http connection to send request and get the response in an stand alone java application, can any one help me how can i proceed with this????

Comment: By the way, feel free to "accept" an answer if it has been most helpful to you.  (though you might be an unregistered user, and I'm not sure if that's possible?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("www.google.com");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        connection.getInputStream();
                    // do something with the input stream here

    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(null != connection) { connection.disconnect(); }
    }
```

Comment: For safety, you should check for null on your connection reference in the finally block

Comment: @jeroen / mike if the response is html how can i get it??

Comment: @user323101 - you can wrap the InputStream returned from the connection in a BufferedReader, and use a StringBuilder to append each line returned from bufferedReader.readLine().

Answer (score 2):

You can use [URLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) class bundled with standard Java (since JDK 1.0!), or a higher level HTTP client such as [Apache's HTTPCLIENT](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) which will provide, in addition to plain HTTP, higher level components like cookies, standard headers and more.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of answers have already pointed out Apache HTTP Client, but they link to version 3.x, which is no longer maintained. You should use version 4, which has a slightly different API, if you want to use this library: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/index.html